# Do I need a transform for my map?

Tags: navigation, mapping, rviz, map-server, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to view my map in rviz and it says "No transform from [map] to [/base_link]".

It also seems to be displaying my map in the YZ plane.

I haven't seen it mentioned elsewhere, though. Am I supposed to provide a transformation for the map?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9391/do-i-need-a-transform-for-my-map?/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2011-03-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will need a transform from the /map frame to /base_link. However, there only needs to be a path between /map and /base_link, not a direct transform. Usually, the transform setup looks something like /map->/odom->/base_link.

These transforms are usually provided by a localization node such as [amcl](http://ros.org/wiki/amcl) or a SLAM node such as [gmapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping).

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-19**:
@mbj: If this question and answer isn't solving your problem (and none of the others on ROS Answers is either), please ask a new question, including anything you have tried to solve your problem but has failed.

**Comment by [mbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/265/mbj/) on 2011-05-19**:
I'm trying to run the navigation stack. As you know, in the navigation stack there is a amcl_node. Well, I publish this node and I can see them in rxgraph, but it is not publishing the tf map -> odom and I receive this error. What I'm doing wrong?? Thanks!
"Waiting on transform from /base_link to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error: Frame id /map does not exist!"